# How to use OSM Bright with Mapnik Renderd

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, cartocss

I have set up an OSM tile server using instructions at this blog -
http://seshagiriprabhu.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/building-an-openstreetmap-tile-server-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

The slippymap renders fine and work nice. 
Now, I want to change the style of the map to OSM Bright. I do not want to (rather, do not have technical expertise to) make any changes to the template.
I wish to learn how to render my maps usng OSM Bright or any other Carto CSS templates. 
I have searched around the net for quite a few days, but cannot find any simple step by step instructions on how to make my mapnik Renderd to display maps with OSM Bright template.

My instance runs on Ubuntu 12.04. Please give me a step by step guide on how to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you just need to export your CartoCSS as final Mapnik style:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/CartoCSS
You might need to adapt your configuration to embedd this new style:
http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/building-a-tile-server-from-packages/

Comment: That is my query exactly. Once I export the CartoCSS (using tilemill?) - what do I do with the exported files? Where do I place them, which files should I overwrite.